# Two ajax post simultaneously on one link click jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using one link which has class name `next` and id `end`.

On clcik on it both class name and id i am using jquery post.

The issue i am getting is sometimes the ajax request fires multiple times on one click.on one click i am getting data from one url and simultaneously saving these data into db by another url.So sometimes there are some issues coming while inserting into db.sometimes null values enters and sometimes multiple rows entering into db.So how can i write these two functions so that both will work perfectly?

```
$('.next').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = [];
    var answer = [];
    var le = '';
    $('.answertext').each(function (index, element) {
        result.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('.answer').each(function (index, element) {
        answer.push($(this).val());
    });
    le = $('#level').val();
    mle = $('#mainlevel').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'matchanswers.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            result: result,
            answer: answer,
            level: le,
            mle: mle
        },
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            // show indicator
        },
        complete: function () {
            // hide indicator
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.quizform').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#end').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sublev = $('#level').val();
    var score = $('#count').val();
    if (sublev < 11) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submitanswers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                sublev: sublev,
                score: score
            },
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // show indicator
            },
            complete: function () {
                // hide indicator
            },
            success: function (data2) {}
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getanswers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                sublev: sublev,
                score: score
            },
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // show indicator
            },
            complete: function () {
                // hide indicator
            },
            success: function (data3) {
                if (data3) {
                    $('.quizform').html("");
                    $('form :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#logout').removeAttr("disabled");
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data3);
                    $('#sum').html("Your Total Score for level - " + obj[0] + " is " + obj[1] + " in " + obj[2] + "secs");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe you should wait for the first call to end before running the ajax call that writes? Running both concurrently will - obviously - ensure issues like you are describing. Do both actions #end and .next be separate actions?

Comment: if you look at the code both are separate actions only

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the event trigger like :

```
$('.next').live('click', function (e) {
    if(e.handled !== true){ // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        e.handled = true;
        //Your code

    }
});



$('#end').live('click', function (e) {
    if(e.handled !== true){ // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        e.handled = true;
        //Your code

    }
});
```

By doing so, you will stop multiple event trigger which is quite a common problem and should solve your problem.

Edit :

Your full code will be :

```
$('.next').live('click', function (e) {
    if (e.handled !== true) { // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        e.handled = true;
        //Your code

        e.preventDefault();
        var result = [];
        var answer = [];
        var le = '';
        $('.answertext').each(function (index, element) {
            result.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('.answer').each(function (index, element) {
            answer.push($(this).val());
        });
        le = $('#level').val();
        mle = $('#mainlevel').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'matchanswers.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                result: result,
                answer: answer,
                level: le,
                mle: mle
            },
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // show indicator
            },
            complete: function () {
                // hide indicator
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.quizform').html(data);
            }
        });

    }
});



$('#end').live('click', function (e) {
    if (e.handled !== true) { // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        e.handled = true;
        //Your code

        e.preventDefault();
        var sublev = $('#level').val();
        var score = $('#count').val();
        if (sublev < 11) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'submitanswers.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    sublev: sublev,
                    score: score
                },
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // show indicator
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // hide indicator
                },
                success: function (data2) {}
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getanswers.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    sublev: sublev,
                    score: score
                },
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // show indicator
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // hide indicator
                },
                success: function (data3) {
                    if (data3) {
                        $('.quizform').html("");
                        $('form :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#logout').removeAttr("disabled");
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data3);
                        $('#sum').html("Your Total Score for level - " + obj[0] + " is " + obj[1] + " in " + obj[2] + "secs");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: under end click,if you look at the code,i have one if else statement.So for that how can i write this code?

Comment: No. simply add all code inside the click event in what i have marked as `//Your code ` and it will work. You are triggering multiple click events and that is the reason why null values are getting inserted probably. Try wrapping it up and see the result. Ive had same issue and this solved it.

Comment: but for end click i have to check for one condition with if and else.under if it will post to one url and under else it will post to another url.Then how to handle it by your code?

Comment: Yes. i dont think there is any problem with the condition checking provided the value is indeed a number. Anyways ill edit the answer to include your code as well and you copy paste the same and see if it solves your issue

Comment: By using this it is not going to getanswers.php url

Comment: Try alerting `sublev` value. The reason why its not going to that page is because of the condition `if (sublev < 11)` that you have set.

Comment: it is not alerting after using e.handled on end click

Answer (score 0):

You are firing click on same click even if id and class are different the link is same.

```
 $('.next').live('click', function(e)
```

fires one ajax call and

```
$('#end').live('click', function(e)
```

fires another, what you can do is fire one ajax on success of other

```
$('.next').live('click', function(e)  { ...
     success: function(data) { $.ajax({
                url: 'submitanswers.php', }
```

but this is not good practice

Comment: I am using Jquery ui datepicker.The year range is working fine in all browser and also 
     in ie8 and above.But the year field is showing blank in below versions of ie8.
     My code is as below,
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var pickerOpts = {
                        minDate: new Date("1970-01-01"),
                        maxDate: new Date(),
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                        yearRange: "1970:2014"
                        }
       </script>